# Unity unable to export Android project on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, unity-game-engine, build

I am trying to export a Unity project to Android on a Mac machine but getting this exception:

> ExitGUIException: Exception of type 'UnityEngine.ExitGUIException'
>   was thrown.
>       UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ExitGUI () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUIUtility.cs:152)
>       UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSdkRoot.Browse (System.String sdkPath)
>       UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.GetInstance ()
>       UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>       UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>       UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PrepareForBuild (BuildOptions options, BuildTarget target)
>       UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PrepareForBuild (BuildOptions options, BuildTarget target)
>       UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.PrepareForBuild (BuildOptions options, BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:87)
>       UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

It doesn't seems to come from my project code and on C# the project builds properly. Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason Unity is not telling you that Android SDK path is not configured and instead giving this error. This issue is solved by setting Unity to point to Android SDK.